# Correct ill formed XML before I deserialize it

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

Due to a PHP error in another product I sometimes get an ill formed XML response, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customfields>
</customfields>Warning
Router: https://example.com/api/index.php?/Tickets/TicketCustomField/Get
file_put_contents(./__swift/cache/SWIFT_Loader.cache): failed to open stream: Invalid argument (C:/Kayako/support/__swift/library/Loader/class.SWIFT_Loader.php:1630)
```

Does a safe method exist to clean up this string before I deserialize it?

The claim of duplicate is correct, but the linked duplicate does not give a working solution.

The current temporary solution, only works if the starting string is valid XML and the appended error does not contain another closing tag which matches the root tag:

```
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled;
var tidyStreamContents = Regex.Match(streamContents, @"^<\?xml.*?\?>\s*?<(.*?)>.*</(\1)>", options, Regex.InfiniteMatchTimeout).ToString();
```

Comment: You could drop everything after the last `>`, somewhat naive but it could work. Have you considered contacting the customer support of the product?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) to treat invalid XML as HTML, clean it up, and output as string for further processing:

```
using CsQuery;

var cq = CQ.CreateFromFile("input.txt");
var sCleanXML = cq("customfields").RenderSelection;
```

Input (content of `input.txt`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customfields>
</customfields>Warning
Router: https://example.com/api/index.php?/Tickets/TicketCustomField/Get
file_put_contents(./__swift/cache/SWIFT_Loader.cache): failed to open stream: Invalid argument (C:/Kayako/support/__swift/library/Loader/class.SWIFT_Loader.php:1630)
```

Output (value of `sCleanXML`):

```
<customfields> </customfields>
```

An alternative would be using [XmlReader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5700945/897326) or [HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/996577/897326).